# Adding properties to a variable made with "require" in Titanium

Tags: variables, properties, titanium, require

For example, in the following code:

```
var MyCustomView = require('MyCustomView');
var myView = new MyCustomView('A message!');
Titanium.UI.currentWindow.add(myView);
```

I want to add a visible=false property to myView. Can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can add any properties you want, this works:

```
myView.visible = false;
```

It depends a lot on what you are wanting to accomplish, but since you are adding the `myView` to a window, I am assuming that it is inherited from a Ti.UI.View, which means that you can set the `visible` property which can hide / show the view.